# Why can't a Promise be covariant

Tags: scala, types, promise, future, covariance

In Scala, a Future is defined to be covariant whereas a Promise is invariant. It is said that a Promise can almost be made contravariant (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7467). Why is this the case?

Comment: There is a simple rule: if you can get a value out of it, then it is covariant (Try, Future, List, Vector, Option, ...). If you can put a value into it, then this is contravariant (Promise, Ordering, Consumer, ...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If promise were covariant you would be able to do:

```
val p: Promise[Any] = Promise[String]()
p.success(1)
```

thereby completing a `Promise[String]` with an `Int` which would be unsafe.

Answer (score 3):

A `Promise` is a mutable API, which does not fare well with covariance. `Future`s don't suffer this problem because you cannot manually complete them like you do with a `Promise`.

Let's say we have:

```
class Animal
class Cat extends Animal
class Dog extends Animal
```

If you want `Promise[A]` to be covariant over `A`, that means we want `Promise[Cat] <: Promise[Animal]` and `Promise[Dog] <: Promise[Animal]`. Let's suppose we can do this.

Okay, so let's say we have a `Promise[Cat]`:

```
val p: Promise[Cat] = ...
```

By our supposition, it's also a `Promise[Animal]`:

```
val q: Promise[Animal] = p
```

`Promise` has a method called `complete` which accepts a `Try[T]`, which is also covariant. This means that a `Try[Dog]` is also a `Try[Animal]`. See where this is leading?

We'd be able to call:

```
val value: Try[Dog] = ...

q.complete(value)
```

Which would be legal, because we're trying to complete a `Promise[Animal]` with a `Try[Animal]`, but *oops*, we also just tried to complete a `Promise[Cat]` with a `Promise[Dog]`.

Comment: Mutability is not a problem for variance here. I think `Promise` could be made contravariant.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov It it definitely a problem for covariance, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: It's a problem for covariance, but not for **variance**

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. But I will accept @Lee's answer as it was posted 1m before yours and they're in essence the same :).